# Accessing UITableView cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have a like button on a cell, and the number of likes being shown beside it.
I have created all the cells in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and I have tagged each cell with it's indexPath. Now, when somebody taps the "like" button, I want to show the updated number without having to reload the entire table.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll show the barebones of my code:

```
-()cellForRowAtIndexPath{
...

cell.Plus.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.Plus addTarget:self action:@selector(plusBtnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

...
}



-(void) plusBtnClick:(id)sender{
//update the number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your button is a subview of your cell's content view `MyCell *cell = [[sender superview] superview]` will give you a pointer to the containing cell. Update the text using `cell.likeLabel.text = whatEverValue`

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an NSIndexPath using the tag. See below for the code that I put into the plusBtnClick function.

```
NSIndexPath *plusIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:senderButton.tag inSection:0];
CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:plusIndexPath];
cell.ScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)scoreCount++];
```